Block non-transparent pixels in CS6
Photoshop has an option to block all transparent pixels: 
Is there an opposite to this action - blocking all non-transparent (fully opaque) pixels so that you only draw on transparency? Preferably a single click one.

Just move a layer to the bottom of the layer stack. Whatever you paint will only be visible if there are no pixels in any layers above it.
